# Copying information at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

Script that copies information on button click and then returns the original text loses some of the button's content.

[image]

[image]

[image]

missing icon from Font Avesome.
Can this be fixed somehow?

I'm a newbie, I'll be glad for a detailed answer.

html:

```
<p id="battlenet-id">gameid#26737</p>
<p id="xbox-id">gameid#5423</p>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-st battlenet" onclick="copyToClipboard('battlenet-id', this)"><i class="fab fa-battle-net"></i> Battle.net</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-st xbox" onclick="copyToClipboard('xbox-id', this);"><i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i> Xbox</a></li>
```

js

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId, thisButton) {
  let oldText = thisButton.textContent
  thisButton.textContent = '!Copied!'
  const timeout = setTimeout(function() { thisButton.textContent = oldText }, 3000);
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(" Copied to clipboard!");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Node.textContent - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

> Both `textContent` and `innerText` remove child nodes when altered

A good option would be using a `span` tag around the text inside your `a`, so that the `i` icon element is not altered when modifying the `textContent`.

In your case, the resulting HTML code will look like this:

```html
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-st xbox" onclick="copyToClipboard('xbox-id', this);"><i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i> <span>Xbox</span></a></li>
```

And I think to copy the whole content of the `a` tag you need to use `innerHTML` instead, otherwise you would get only the text.

Or you could just save both `i` and `span` elements saving a copy of them independently and append them again after.

Answer (score 1):

Only using `textContent` won't be suffice to keep the `icon` after copying the text. To have the original content (text + icon) reverted after performing the copy, you'd need to use a combination of `textContent` and `innerHTML` attributes.

Here's a demo:

```js
/** select all the buttons that have the copy feature based on the "link-st" class */
const toBeCopiedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.link-st');

/** 
 * loop through those buttons and add a click event listener to each one that perform the copy feature
 */
toBeCopiedElements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  /** 
   * el: references the current button in the forEach loop
   * oldHTML: has the initial HTML content of the button 
   * aux: the input element that is used to perform the "copy" command
   */
  const oldHTML = el.innerHTML,
    aux = document.createElement('input');

  /** set the buttons text as the newly created input's value */
  aux.value = el.textContent;

  /** perform the copy command and the cleanups afterwards (the next 4 line) */
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(aux);

  /** replace the buttons HTML content with "!Copied!" text. Must use "innerHTML" here in order to fully remove the old text and icon */
  el.innerHTML = '!Copied!';

  /** reset the button's HTML content (using ".innerHTML") to the original content after 3s */
  setTimeout(() => el.innerHTML = oldHTML, 3000);
}));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<!-- Removed the inline event listeners and switched to the modern way of atttaching listeners (using "addEventListener" methodd) -->
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-st battlenet"><i class="fab fa-battle-net"></i> Battle.net</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-st xbox"><i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i> Xbox</a></li>
```

> The above demo is definitely not the only way to get things done. There might be some other ways most notably using the modern [`Clipboard API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) to have the copy-to-clipboard feature.